# how to find empty html td cell and change back ground color through php html css

Tags: html, css

how to find empty/error value html  cell and change back ground color through php html css

Here status column don't have a value, I want to change the body class background color to red if any of the html table cell value is empty and color to green if all values are present and color to yellow if status has value "E" . Could you please help me on this.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Export/rbody.css">
<BODY class="red">
    <tr>
       <th>database()</th>
       <th>id</th>
       <th>PROCESS</th>
       <th>SCHEDULENEXTDUE</th>
       <th>STATUS</th>
       <th>LASTUPDATEDON</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>CUST_TEST_DB</td>
       <td>5</td>
       <td>restart</td>
       <td>2018-02-02 07:35:52</td>
       <td></td>
       <td>2018-02-02 07:35:52</td>
    </tr>
```

```css
 body { 
     color: #D8D8BF; 
     background-color: black;
     background-repeat: repeat-y;
    }

    a:link { color: #00FFAA; text-decoration: underline; } 
    a:visited { color: #FFFF44; text-decoration: underline; } 

    .green {
     background-image: url(green.gif);
    }


    .red {
     background-image: url(red.gif);
    }

.yellow {
     background-image: url(yellow.gif);
    }
```

Comment: can you use js?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`:empty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) pseudo selector in CSS.

```css
td:empty {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>database()</th>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>PROCESS</th>
    <th>SCHEDULENEXTDUE</th>
    <th>STATUS</th>
    <th>LASTUPDATEDON</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>CUST_TEST_DB</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>restart</td>
    <td>2018-02-02 07:35:52</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>2018-02-02 07:35:52</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the css `empty` selector, like this perhaps:

```
td:empty{
   background:red;
}
```

---

After reading the comments and then reading the question in more detail I appreciate that the original answer I gave, whilst definitely succinct, was perhaps not sufficient in all respects. The following quickly written piece of javascript does some basic tests and assigns a rudimentary class accordingly.

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <th>database()</th>
       <th>id</th>
       <th>PROCESS</th>
       <th>SCHEDULENEXTDUE</th>
       <th>STATUS</th>
       <th>LASTUPDATEDON</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>CUST_TEST_DB</td>
       <td>5</td>
       <td>restart</td>
       <td>2018-02-02 07:35:52</td>
       <td>E</td>
       <td>2018-02-02 07:35:52</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>CUST_TEST_DB</td>
       <td>5</td>
       <td>restart</td>
       <td></td>
       <td>2018-02-02 07:35:52</td>
       <td>2018-02-02 07:35:52</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>CUST_TEST_DB</td>
       <td>5</td>
       <td></td>
       <td>restart</td>
       <td>2018-02-02 07:35:52</td>
       <td>2018-02-02 07:35:52</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<style>
    td:empty{
        background:red;
        display:block;
    }
    .empty{
        background:red;
    }
    .notempty{
        background:green;
    }
    .status_E{
        background:yellow;
    }
</style>
<script>
    Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll('td') ).forEach( function( td ){
        if( td.innerHTML!=''){
            td.classList.add('notempty');
        }
        if( td.innerHTML=='E'){
            td.classList.add('status_E');
        }
        if( td.innerHTML=='' ){
            td.classList.add('empty');
            td.innerHTML='&nbsp;'
        }
    });
</script>
```

or, assuming the data is drawn from a database initially then some pseudo-code to indicate another possible approach ( not tested or debugged )

```
echo "
<table>
    <tr>
       <th>database()</th>
       <th>id</th>
       <th>PROCESS</th>
       <th>SCHEDULENEXTDUE</th>
       <th>STATUS</th>
       <th>LASTUPDATEDON</th>
    </tr>";


/* assumed names of columns */
$fields=array('db','id','process','nextdue','status','updated');
$class='';

while( $row=$results->fetch() ){

    foreach( $fields as $field ){
        if( empty( $row->$field ) ) $class=" class='empty'";
        if( $field=='status' && $row->$field=='E' ) $class=" class='status_E'";
        echo "<td{$class}>{$row->$field}</td>";
    }


}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Use condition class <td class="<?php if(!$data) { echo 'red'; } ?>"><?php echo $data; ?></td> In CSS red{
   background:red;
}

Comment: @twitch, is that better than what's above?

Comment: You can added condition what if its status = " "; Does CSS validates that? I replied after Kuba Zabielski how did this end up here??WEIRD

Comment: If `status = ' '`, I wouldn't output the space. Heck, it probably wouldn't be in the db as a space to begin with. But yeah, you could go that route.